# List all VM's by their port mirroring settings PowerShell

Tags: powershell, virtual-machine, port, hyper-v, mirroring

I'm looking for a way to list all VM's on a machine by the type of mirroring they have set using PowerShell.

For Example:

```
Get-VM -PortMirroring Source
```

And I'll see all VM's that have network adapters with Port Mirroring set to Source.
But I know that Get-VM doesn't take PortMirroring as a parameter, so I'm wondering if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not this easy, as `PortMirroring` is not the property of a VM, but rather a property of its network adapter. You need to iterate VMs' network adapters and output VMs that have at least 1 adapter that has `PortMirroringMode` set to "Source".

```
$vms=get-vm
$filteredVMs=@()
foreach ($vm in $vms) { 
   $nas=get-vmnetworkadapter -vm $vm # adapter list
   foreach ($na in $nas) {
       if ($na.PortMirroringMode -eq 'Source') {
           $filteredVMs+=$vm
           break 
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly, just added a $filteredVMs to the end so it returns the VMs when ran as a script. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
get-vm | Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Where-Object {$_.PortMirroringMode -eq 'Source'}
```